# Using Grunt, is there a way to reuse html snippets and have Intellij IDEA still recognize the snippet as html?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, gruntjs

I'm developing a web app in intellij idea and I have a need to reuse some html in my app.  For example, some production code depends on the html so I need the same snippet of html my unit tests.  I don't like the DRY violation of copying this html between two html files.

Is there a way I can reuse pieces of html but have intellij still know that the reusable snippet is part an html file?  I'd still like all the nice features like highlighting and auto completion to be available in the snippet.

This is a single page app with no back end yet.  In other words, it's all html/css/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I hate copying and pasting HTML, too which is why I wrote [modest](https://github.com/goalzen/modest).  Look at the documentation and let me know if this was the kind of thing you had in mind; I may have other suggestions.

There is also [grunt-modest](https://github.com/goalzen/grunt-modest) for creating a deployment step, since you mentioned "grunt."

Comment: This looks pretty good, I'll have to play with it a little bit to make sure.  [I have some qs about the examples](https://github.com/goalzen/modest/wiki/Examples): Is "example.xhtml" the rendered template? I think the second example would be easier to understand if you showed output and either removed header/footers or showed how they're set.  I like complete, working examples so I can play with them, but that example is incomplete.  I'll read the full documentation next.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've been working on improving the documentation/examples, so it's good to have feedback.  I'll try to put up some gists of working code.

Comment: Send a message to me on github (or submit an issue) so I can make some custom examples that will help with your project.  I think we can both help each other--I need some good ideas for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin named [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes).  If you have really simple use cases (no need to pass in parameters), this is probably the best tool for the job.

If you have more complex use cases, there's also [grunt-includes-replace](https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace) which has extra functionality.

Answer (score -1):

please can you clarify what your code looks like? Is it javascript with some HTML snippets? Smth like:

```
livereloadUtils.getSnippet = function() {    
     snippet += '<p>my html code here</p>';
     ...
```

WebStorm normally recognizes such snippets as HTML, and syntax highlighting/completion is available. You don't need to do anything special to enable it

Comment: My code looks like html.  It will probably be wrapped in some templating language though.

Comment: ok. Your code looks like HTML, but Idea doesn't recognize it as HTML? Or? Sorry, but your answer didn't give me any clue - it's still not clear what you code looks like, so I have no idea if it's possible to configure the IDE accordingly